# Snapshot loading random data from cache before getting from the server

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a streambuilder where I'm loading products

```
StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: _ref.collection("products").where("category", isEqualTo: 
    widget.selectedCategory.nameLabel).orderby("standing",descending:false).limit(10)
        
    builder: (context, snapshot) {

      if(snapshot.hasData){

         if(snapshot.data!.docs.isNotEmpty) {
             for (var changes in snapshot.data!.docChanges) {
             //adding data to list<Products> products for pagination
          }
         }

            return ProductsList.vertical(
               scrollController: _scrollProducts,
               products: products,
               scroll: true,
          );
     }
```

The problem is I'm receiving more than 10 documents. If there is cache data, it will load that first then load the actual data ordered by 'standing'.

This problem exists mostly on the first load when cache data is not correct. How can we fix this?

Answer (score 0):

What you're describing sounds like the expected behavior. The Firebase SDK for Firestore will:

1. immediately give you the documents from the local cache that meet the query conditions,
2. then reach out to the server to get latest content, with which it then updates its local cache.
3. finally fire an additional event on the stream with this latest content.

I don't think there's a way to bypass the first event on your stream in Flutter, which you can detect that snapshots come from the cache (and may not be up to date with the server) by checking their `document.metadata.isFromCache` property.